# cannot bind a port altough LISTEN

Tags: port, ipv4, netstat, bindings

I'm new to this problem I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via VMware

My problem is to bind port 6703 i tried alot of commands to check if this port or open or not

Error Message is

```
Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6703
```

My result after (("try")) to bind it by a process

```
st@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6703
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:6703 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 6678/java
```

but i noticed that when i used this command before tried any process on this port got no thing !

The commands are

```
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6703
```

and

```
sudo lsof -i :6703
```

if there are any details you want i can provide you with it as i'm new and don't know what is supposed to be shared

Thanks in advance

Another notice i'm using wireless connection in win8 OS and didn't got this in ubuntu but the internet working with auto Ethernet

Can i make ubuntu got the wireless configuration in ubuntu like win8 ?

Comment: Check your SELinux logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but i'm new sorry , is this file in file system or what ?

Comment: Yes, likely in `/var/log` somewhere.

Comment: i found folder named selinux and empty !

Comment: Can anyone help on this?